# Header does not disappear when a popup pops up

Tags: html, header, popup, elementor

I made, with elementor pro, a popup. My header is made with html and a sticky header effect. But when I click on "markten" inside my header, I want to pop up this popup. This does work, but when this popup appears, I want my header to disappear - but it doesn't do that.

I have already tried to alter the z-index, but with no success...

Can you guys help me out? Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you are using sticky effect. you might remove sticky effect using JS when sidebar is clicked, and restore the sticky effect when close button is pressed.